# Eliminating duplicate values based on criteria in R

Tags: r, subset, tidyverse

I am cleaning an administrative dataset. I have two questions, and I am not sure of the logical order to answer them for my coding purposes. I have data similar to this:

```
name <- c("Smith, John J", "Smith, John Jay", "Smith, Jane", "Smith, Joe M")
event <- c('123', '123', '124', '125')
type <- c('s', 'a', 'v', 's')
df <- data.frame(name, event,type)
```

***First***, I want to eliminate the extra `event` record for individuals that have both `type = 'a'` and `type = 's'` records. When they have both, I only want the record with `type = 'a'` observation. ***Note***: this is conditional on the `event` record being the same. As you can see in the `df` there are two `event 123` records for "John Smith".

***Second***, does the fact that there individuals who have their middle name spelled out versus just an initial, and those without a listed middle name/initial in the `name` field an issue for this? If so, I was planning on separating that column out with:

```
separate(df, name, c('name','middle'), " ")
```

Ideally, my end goal would look like this:

```
           name event type
1 Smith, John J   123    a
2   Smith, Jane   124    v
3  Smith, Joe M   125    s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this while accounting for the possible inconsistencies in middle names, you'll have to split the name into its different components:

```
# Be careful about the stringsAsFactors setting
df <- data.frame(name, event, type, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
  separate(name, c("last", "other"), sep = ", ", remove = FALSE) %>%
  separate(other, c("first", "middle"), sep = " ", fill = "right") %>%
  # Treat people as the same individual if their first and last names
  #   match, ignore middle name
  group_by(first, last, event) %>%
  # Put 'a' records first
  arrange(desc(type == "a")) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Comment: If the individual has more that one record with a ```type=='a'``` would the ```slice(1)``` only eliminate the first record then? Should I be using ```slice(n())```?

Comment: `slice(1)` will only keep one record per group - it's selecting the first row in each group. So if you only want one row per person, `slice(1)` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

After grouping by 'event' and a 'grp' created by removing the last word in 'name', then reorder the 'name' based on the occurrence of 'a' in 'type' and `slice` the last element

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    group_by(event, grp = str_remove(name, "\\s*\\w+$")) %>%
    mutate(name = name[order(type != 'a')]) %>% 
    slice(n()) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   event [3]
#  name          event type 
#  <fct>         <fct> <fct>
#1 Smith, John J 123   a    
#2 Smith, Jane   124   v    
#3 Smith, Joe M  125   s
```

Comment: What do the last two functions ```ungroup``` and then ```select(-grp)``` do?

Comment: @mtotof `select` with `-` is to remove that column from the dataset and if it is a grouped column, it needs to be `ungroup`ed before removing as the attributes for group are present in the dataset